# Stacking matrices to make a matrix with sites of parent matrices map as block diagonals

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

How stack matrices as follows in python such that elements of parent matrices make a block diagonal at the same block diagonal site of the daughter matrix.
example:
I have four matrices AA,AB,BA, BB

I want to make the matrix out as shown in attached image.[image: Making out from AA,AB,BA,BB]

Comment: There is an error in your example. And for your task: read numpy's [slicing-docs](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.indexing.html#basic-slicing-and-indexing).

Comment: I'd make a (2,2,2,2) array from those blocks, and do a transpose to rearrange the pieces.  Then back to a (4,4) array.  We'd have to work out the required transpose by trial and error or some sort of systematic thinking.

Comment: I want to know if there is a quick way like vstack

Comment: `vstack` can't reorder the blocks.  `stack` might be able to.

Answer (score 1):

```
In [35]: arr = np.arange(1,17).reshape(4,4)
In [36]: arr2 = arr.reshape(2,2,2,2)
In [37]: arr2
Out[37]: 
array([[[[ 1,  2],
         [ 3,  4]],

        [[ 5,  6],
         [ 7,  8]]],


       [[[ 9, 10],
         [11, 12]],

        [[13, 14],
         [15, 16]]]])
```

I did some trial and errors with transpose idea but didn't get any where.

But lets step back an try sliced insertion:

```
In [42]: out = np.zeros_like(arr)
In [43]: out[::2,::2]=arr2[0,0]
In [44]: out[::2,1::2]=arr2[0,1]
In [45]: out
Out[45]: 
array([[1, 5, 2, 6],
       [0, 0, 0, 0],
       [3, 7, 4, 8],
       [0, 0, 0, 0]])
```

This seems to be a workable solution.  That could be put into a loop (or 2).

```
In [50]: out = np.zeros_like(arr)
In [51]: for i,j in np.ndindex(2,2):
    ...:     out[i::2,j::2] = arr2[i,j]
    ...:     
In [52]: out
Out[52]: 
array([[ 1,  5,  2,  6],
       [ 9, 13, 10, 14],
       [ 3,  7,  4,  8],
       [11, 15, 12, 16]])
```

Splitting `out` into the 4d array may help us visualize a transformation from `Out[37]`:

```
In [57]: out.reshape(2,2,2,2)
Out[57]: 
array([[[[ 1,  5],
         [ 2,  6]],

        [[ 9, 13],
         [10, 14]]],


       [[[ 3,  7],
         [ 4,  8]],

        [[11, 15],
         [12, 16]]]])
```

But maybe the more obvious iterative solution is fast enough.

This, for example, creates the correct 2x2 blocks:

```
In [59]: arr2.transpose(0,2,3,1)
Out[59]: 
array([[[[ 1,  5],
         [ 2,  6]],

        [[ 3,  7],
         [ 4,  8]]],


       [[[ 9, 13],
         [10, 14]],

        [[11, 15],
         [12, 16]]]])
```

and one more swap:

```
In [62]: arr2.transpose(2,0,3,1).reshape(4,4)
Out[62]: 
array([[ 1,  5,  2,  6],
       [ 9, 13, 10, 14],
       [ 3,  7,  4,  8],
       [11, 15, 12, 16]])
```